# Create a file along with writing into it with a single line on the command line

Tags: linux, files, terminal

How do I create a file named hello.sh with the contents "echo hello world" in one line using/on terminal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `echo` and direct the output to the file:

```
echo "echo hello world" > hello.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

In a terminal, you could:

- Use `echo` to place a line in a file, like `echo 'echo hello world' > hello.sh`.
- Use `vi` to edit `hello.sh` (vi `hello.sh`).  Once in the editor you would use <kbd>i</kbd> to enter Insert mode, type the contents you wish the file to have, then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter Normal mode.  In Normal mode, you would use <kbd>:wq</kbd> to save the file and exit `vi`.
- Use `nano` to edit the file (nano `hello.sh`).  `nano` is a simpler editor without "modes".  You simply type the contents you want and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to save the file, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit `nano`.

If you have access to a graphical environment, there are many text editors you can use and they depend mainly on the desktop environment provided by your distribution.

- In GNOME 2, you could use `gedit`.  It's typically under Applications > Accessories > Text Editor.
- In GNOME 3, you would also use `gedit`, but you would find it by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> (Also known as the Windows Key) and scrolling through the icons (or beginning to type "Text Editor").
- In KDE, you could use `kate`.  It's found in the main menu under Accessories.

Comment: thxs but was looking for a one-liner

Comment: My first bullet point is a one-liner.